# Object [object Object] has no method 'FixedScroll' Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Said website: http://sebastiangraz.com/projects/kbt

I wanted to add a script (FitScroll) to my wordpress template: http://codepen.io/ozgursagiroglu/full/tdpDr

This is how I enqueued it:

```
function kbt_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'kbt-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

wp_enqueue_script( 'kbt-fitscroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/fitscroll.js', array('jquery'), '20120206', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'kbt-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/js.js', array('jquery'), '20120206', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'kbt-validate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.validate.min.js', array('jquery'), '20120206', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'kbt-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array('jquery'), '20120206', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'kbt-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '20120206', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'kbt-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20130115', true );

if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
}
}
```

I called the script with a noconflict wrapper

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('body').FixedScroll({
     elements: '.module', // required
     delay: 500 // millisecond, optional
    });
});
```

I made sure I don't load jQuery twice. I've checked everywhere.

I still get this message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'FixedScroll'
```

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: could you check the HTML source code in someday i recommend a Web Inspector Fire Bug or Chrome's inspector and check that the file is loaded and that the file path is correct if so could you post that snippet of the HTML that has been built

Comment: Is that a typo? FitScroll or FixedScroll?

Comment: Yes it was. From the documentation source even: https://github.com/ozgursagiroglu/fitscroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its `FitScroll` not `FixedScroll` try this,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('body').FitScroll({ // FitScroll not FixedScroll
       elements: '.module', // required
       delay: 500 // millisecond, optional
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow that is super weird. Even the documentation says FixedScroll (https://github.com/ozgursagiroglu/fitscroll) What a bummer

Comment: Ya there is mistake on `Github`, but you have to correct it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('body').FitScroll({
     elements: '.module', // required
     delay: 500 // millisecond, optional
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Fitscroll` instead of `FixedScroll`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('body').FitScroll({
     elements: '.module', // required
     delay: 500 // millisecond, optional
    });
});
```

Next time, if you confused whether the name is correct or not, just digging directly into your plugin which is in your case located at the URL: http://sebastiangraz.com/projects/kbt/wp-content/themes/kbt/js/fitscroll.js?ver=20120206

And from this you can figure out the correct name of the function which is this:

```
$.fn.FitScroll = function(opt){
    // Plugin code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I never really considered that the documentation could be wrong, because they rarely are. It didn't even come into mind to check the function name.